# How to get details from JIRA using the webservices

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, jira, jira-plugin

I want to use web service in my Java EE application to get the details from JIRA.
My project scenario is to get details like from one Project.

1. How many defects are open for a project
2. How many are reopen
3. How many hours we spend for each defect and then we will store in our DB

please can any one help me out by suggesting which web service is better suitable and how can expose to jira.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are developing a Java application then I think the obvious choice is to use [JIRA REST Java Client Library](https://ecosystem.atlassian.net/wiki/display/JRJC/Home). It's developed by Atlassian.